# DefaultAzureCredential is not picking credential from the msal-node token cache

Tags: node.js, azure, electron, azure-ad-msal, azure-identity

I am in the process of integrating the Entra ID to authenticate my Electron application, and to authroize the azure resources for the Service Principal.

Currently, the application is successfully authenticated with Entra ID using the msal-node library, as described in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial-3-sign-in-electron/.

However, when I try to access the CosmosDB and other resources with the DefaultAzureCredential, I am getting the following error.

[image]

Anything I am missing here?

Is there any other way to directly build the credential using the response, such as, tenent id, client id, authority, and accessToken, obtained from the authentication process?

Comment: You can create **environment variables** named `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` and `AZURE_TENANT_ID`  by passing appId, secret and tenant Id as values. Check if these helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1343536/credentialunavailableerror-when-using-defaultazure and  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/identity/identity#defaultazurecredential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add below environment variables in your system:

`AZURE_CLIENT_ID` - **App ID** of your service principal

`AZURE_TENANT_ID` - Your **Tenant ID**

`AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` - Secret **value** of your service principal

You can get values of `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `AZURE_TENANT_ID` from application's **Overview** page:

[image]

For `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`, you can create one **client secret** in your app registration and copy it's **value** that will be visible only once for few seconds:

[image]

Make sure to assign proper **RBAC roles** to the service principal under subscription to authorize the Azure resources.

**References:**

[CredentialUnavailableError when using DefaultAzureCredential - Microsoft Q&A  by **Marilee Turscak-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1343536/credentialunavailableerror-when-using-defaultazure)

[azure-sdk-for-js/sdk/identity/identity at main · Azure/azure-sdk-for-js · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/identity/identity#defaultazurecredential)